# How do you add weight to strokes in Photoshop? I see the option but no results

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, stroke

So I tried to solve this problem on my own, and feel I got halfway there. Now I'm stuck.

I'm trying to convert a drawing to a digital logo (did this successfully in Illustrator already, but was upset about shading options...or lack thereof). I've started outlining my image with the pen tool, but I can't seem to add weight to it without using an ugly brush effect.

At first, I was having trouble getting the Edit > Stroke to work, as it was greyed out. Then I created a new layer via copy for just the path. Now I can select Edit > Stroke and enter a weight and color, but it won't actually change the path at all!

I'm at a loss, and after searching, I still can't find any answers. I'm experimenting on my own, but if any of you are familiar with my problem or are super smart, please help me out!

SCREENSHOT: [http://imgur.com/aG2qo69](https://imgur.com/aG2qo69)

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Edit → Stroke works on selections. If you want to use that command you need to first convert your path into a selection. With the path still there click the pen tool <kbd>P</kbd> then on the top of your screen (default layout of course) you should see `Make Selection`

[image]

After making it into a selection it will work as you intend.

In the long run though it would be better to use the `Make Shape` command and then instead of using Edit → Stroke you could just use the Shapes Stroke and Fill.

In the even longer run you should go back into Illustrator if your goal is a logo and if you get stuck on shading then ask for ideas on that.